# How to detect the NFC (ACR122U) reader and read the ID value of the tag, using Smartcard API

Tags: c#, nfc

I try to read the ID of a NFC tag with the [SmartCard API](http://www.smartcard-api.com/index.shtml), I'm sure there is not much code to implement but I'm totally lost. Here is the code i could provide.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Barcode
{
class MifareCardConfigData
    {

    byte[] UID = null;
    byte[] m_serialNumber = null;

    public MifareCardConfigData(SmartCardAPI.CardModule.CLICS.ClicsCardEdge MifareCard)
        {

        UID = MifareCard.UID;
        Array.Resize(ref m_serialNumber, UID.Length);

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: question please?

Comment: Can you show me how detect the NFC reader and read the ID value of the tag on it

Comment: are you reffering this api, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627646(v=vs.85).aspx ?

Comment: No i use this one. http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcard-api/